# Как сохранить базу данных выбранную директорию EF

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

**Что мне нужно сделать:** допустим пользователь выбрал куда сохранить файл с помощью класса SaveFileDialog,как мне сгенерировать базу данных по этому пути.

**Note:** Не могу понять почему при генерации базы данных программа подвисает.

**Моя сущность для генерации базы данных Article:**

```
 public class Article
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; 
        public Article() { }
        public Article(string title, string text, string image)
        {
            Title = title;
            Text = text;
            Image = image;
        }
    }
```

**ArticleContext**

```
 public class ArticleContext : DbContext
    {
        public ArticleContext() : base("DBConnect") { }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public static void Save<T>(List<T> item) where T : class
        {
            using (var db = new ArticleContext())
            {  
                db.Set<T>().AddRange(item);
                db.SaveChanges();//Сохраняем все изменения, сделанные в базовой базе данных.
            }
        }

    }
```

**DBConnect-страка полученыя к бд**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnect"
        connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ParserHabr;Integrated Security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @Alexander Petrov При генерации базы данных,начинает подввисать gui после создания бд все норм сновиться,то есть когда пользователь нажал на кнопку.

Comment: Первоначальная инициализация контекста и наполнение файла БД - это долгий процесс. Или выводите пользователю сообщение "Ждите" в GUI, или выполняйте код в отдельном потоке/задаче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `DbContext` имеет [конструктор](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext__ctor_System_String_), принимающий параметр `nameOrConnectionString`. То есть в него можно передавать непосредственно строку соединения.

Чтобы им воспользоваться, сделайте в своём классе `ArticleContext` конструктор с аналогичным параметром:

```
public class ArticleContext : DbContext
{
    public ArticleContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
    // ...
}
```

Получив имя файла из `SaveFileDialog`:

```
string filename = saveFileDialog.FileName;
```

используем его для конструирования строки соединения. Чтобы не допустить ошибок экранирования и т. п., применим класс [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.DataSource = @"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

builder.AttachDBFilename = filename;
builder.InitialCatalog = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

string connectionString = builder.ToString();
```

Создаём контекст с этой строкой соединения:

```
var context = new ArticleContext(connectionString);
```

Comment: Почему мне   генерирует базу не указанной директории а на диске 
C:\Users\имя юзера  с  именем файла  C__Users_esel1_Desktop_bd_2332.mdf?  sql server -показывает что она сгенерированная в  правильной каталоге.

Comment: Как странно оно именует  файл как путь и сохранять на диске C:\Users\имя юзера. sql server -показывает что она сгенерированная в правильной каталоге.

Comment: @Vladimir - мне пока некогда, позже посмотрю. Возможно, для указания имени файла следует использовать свойство `AttachDBFilename` вместо `InitialCatalog`.

Comment: Спасибо вам сработало   c AttachDBFilename , но в sql server показывает FOODTEAM_62e972b6186245fba0c4a360b41bfe58. Хотя имя базы данных FOODTEAM ну мне особо это не важно.

Comment: Мне интересно откуда беруться  эти числа 62e972b6186245fba0c4a360b41bfe58.

Comment: @Vladimir - дополнил ответ. Следует использовать сразу оба свойства: и `InitialCatalog`, и `AttachDBFilename`. Тогда и файл размещается в нужном месте, и название у БД будет удобное.

Comment: большое вам спасибо за помощь.